# Book about a boy ending up in a different world

Tags: story-identification, books

I don’t remember the name of the book or who wrote it. I read it in elementary school (2002-2006).

It’s about a boy that is in Colombia or Ecuador? I just know he’s on the equator and I think he’s in a wooded area or a forest and it’s an equinox, I can’t remember if it’s spring or autumn, and he messes with a stone pile? and he ends up in a different universe with I think mythical creatures and he has to get back to his own world before a certain time or he’s stuck in the new world.

That’s really all I remember and that the cover of the book is green. I think it was leaves but I'm not sure, but for sure green.

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.